# syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I am getting this error when trying to click a button with umlaut:

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
                click_on 'Neue Firma hinzufц╪gen'
```

I am testing with Ruby & Capabara.

```
##Create_User_spec.rb 
require 'acceptance/acceptance_helper' 
## Feature 'Create User' 
feature 'Create User' do ## 
Scenario 'Create a User' 
scenario 'Create a User' do 
  ## Login into the service 
  visit 'url' 
  fill_in 'User-username', :with => 'test' 
  fill_in 'User-password', :with => 'test' 
  click_on 'login' 
  click_link 'Test' 
  click_on 'Neue Firma hinzufügen' 
end 
end
```

Comment: Please show the code of that page..

Comment: If you indented your code properly, you'd be more likely to detect such errors yourself.

Answer (score 8):

This also can happen if you have a stray `.` trailing a method, so check for those as well.

Answer (score 7):

It happened to me because of special characters, in my case portuguese signs. I believe the problem is the "ü" in hinzufügen. Looking for a solution yet.

**Edit: found a solution!**

I added the following to the very top of the rb file:

# encoding: utf-8

(don't miss the # sign, it is needed)

Answer (score 3):

This error due to an extra end.Mean you have written an extra end with no matching do.

Comment: ##Create_User_spec.rb

require 'acceptance/acceptance_helper'

## Feature 'Create User'
feature 'Create User' do


 ## Scenario 'Create a User'
 scenario 'Create a User' do
 
  ## Login into the service
  visit 'url'
  fill_in 'User-username', :with => 'test'
  fill_in 'User-password', :with => 'test'
  click_on 'login'
   
  click_link 'Test'
  click_on 'Neue Firma hinzufügen'

 end
end

Comment: Create_User_spec.rb require 'acceptance/acceptance_helper' 
 Feature 'Create User' feature 'Create User' do 

end
Scenario 'Create a User' scenario 'Create a User' do 
  Login into the service visit 'url' fill_in 'User-username', :with => 'test' fill_in 'User-password', :with => 'test' click_on 'login' click_link 'Test' click_on 'Neue Firma hinzufügen' 
end

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well but because I was missing an end. I am following this tutorial

http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html

My model was:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
     @articles = Article.all
    end
```

It needed to be:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
     @articles = Article.all
    end 
end
```

Hope that helps someone.